# Swagger security - mark subpath as public when parent is private? E.g. /api/public/** and /api/**

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I'd like to tell Swagger (via Java) that a set of paths require authentication, e.g. `/api/**` but that a particular subpath does not, e.g. `/api/public/**`.

I thought it might be possible to add a `SecurityContext` for `/api/public/**` like so:

```
SecurityContext.builder()
    .securityReferences(new ArrayList<>())
    .forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/public/**"))
    .build()
```

I.e. in addition to the context I'd built for `/api/**` I could add one for `/api/public/**`, with no security references, and that if I got the ordering right this additional context would match any appropriate path *rather* than the `/api/**` context.

But this isn't how things work - when matching occurs it doesn't just stop at the first match, it actually looks for all matches. So a path like `/api/public/foo` will match both the `/api/*` and `/api/public/**` context.

So is there any way to achieve what I want, i.e. when I use the Swagger UI I'd like not to see a lock icon beside paths like `/api/public/foo`.